# How to use a class generated by JavaScript multiple times on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, file, include

I'm reading a text file into with a temporary email address and let this snippet built a HTML link.

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('temporary_email')[0].innerHTML = "<a href=\"mailto:" + xhttp.responseText + "\">Email</a>";
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/temporary_email.txt", true);
    xhttp.send();
//]]>
</script>
```

The whole thing works as expected and I can just place `<span class="temporary_email"></span>` anywhere and get a link.

**The problem:** it seems I can only fetch this one time; if I have a `mailto:` link in the body and another one in my footer the script won't work. So, I figure this isn't actually a variable and me being a JS noob is the real problem.

*PS: I'm trying to avoid jQuery. Tried a few dummy workarounds like duplicating the script and assigning another name for `document.getElementsByClassName`, but nothing. Basically I'm working for a quick and dirty fix until I know enough JavaScript to do this properly.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're only getting the JS appended to the first instance of the class name match, is because `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an *array* of matched elements.

By using `document.getElementsByClassName('temporary_email')[0]`, you're only ever going to select the first matched element.

You'd need to update to the following code:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

          if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
              var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('temporary_email');

              for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                  elements[i].innerHTML = "<a href=\"mailto:" + xhttp.responseText + "\">Email</a>";
              }  
          }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/temporary_email.txt", true);
    xhttp.send();
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/4hc0nyu1/) a basic fiddle.

This way, you're iterating trough the array, and each one you're changing the `innerHTML` to what you need. Plus, no jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

you could iterate over your  `temporary_email` links and update each of them:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('temporary_email'))
  .forEach(function(el){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        el.innerHTML = "<a href=\"mailto:" + xhttp.responseText + "\">Emai  l</a>";
    }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/temporary_email.txt", true);
    xhttp.send();
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. I honestly don't know which answer is the better one, but I gave G.Hunt the credit because he was a tad faster and explained more in his comment what's happening. Still, big thumbs up to you, too. I spend several hours fiddling with this problem before deciding to post it here.